# Angular 2.0.0 - Mocking Components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, karma-jasmine, primeng

How do you mock a component in Angular 2.0.0 Final Release? I have a problem in mocking a component that has a variable that I use for logic in another component. Specifically, I want to mock a **PrimeNG Datatable** selection.

Sample code below.

**table.component.html**

```
        <p-dataTable
          #table
          [value]="myDatasource"
          [(selection)]="mySelections"
          ...
        >
```

**table.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html'
})

export class TableComponent{
    @ViewChild('table') datatable;
```

**my-component.component.html**

```
<my-table #mytable></my-table>
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('#mytable') mytable;

  myFunction() : void  {
    if(this.mytable.table.selection.length === 0){
       console.log();
    } else{
       console.log();
    }
  }
```

How do I mock it so that I can set values to  the ***selection*** in the **table.component.ts** to test in the **my-component.component.ts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banana-box `[()]` syntax is just shorthand for `[] ()`, where the name of the output `()` is just the name of the input `[]`, suffixed with `Change`. For example

```
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'p-datatable',
  template: `...`
})
class MockDataTable {
  @Input() value;

  @Input() selection;
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Here the output `selectionChange` is the same name as the input `selection`, just suffixed with `Change`. Now we can use the syntax `[(selection)]`. When we emit a value to the `selectionChange`, Angular will change the property that we assign to it accordingly. For example

```
@Component({
  template: '<p-datatable [(selection)]="value"></p-datatable>
})
class ParentComponent {
  value = somevalue;
}

class MockDataTable {
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();

  click() {
    this.selectionChange('new value');
  }
}
```

Here, when `click` is called on the data table, it emits a new event with the value `new value`. Because the `ParentComponent.value` is bound to the `selectionChange`, Angular will automatically change its value to `new value`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am using primeNG's datatable and the p-datatable component is out of my control. On the other hand, how do I mock the table? Do I use the overrideComponent in testBed?

Comment: I just showed you. Create another component as the mock and add it to the `declarations`, instead of using PrimeNg's

Comment: Yes, I remembered but it was a service. Nonetheless, should I configure the mocked table in the TestBed.configureTestingModule or TestBed.overrideComponent?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about a service. I meant I just showed you with the code above. And you should add it to the declarations of the configureTestingModule

Comment: Actually, I didn't import the PrimeNg's. Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tA104Zc8mUZpKKMxvmj3?p=catalogue

Comment: Just add the MockDataTable above the `declarations` in the configureTestingModule so that the component you are testing uses it. Because the `MockDataTable` `selector` `p-datatable` you component you are testing will use that component. This is how you mock a component

Comment: It doesn't seem to be able to pick up the mocked component.

Comment: The selector is wrong. It should the `p-dataTable` with a capital `T`

Comment: Console.log says the data is undefined. Here is a plunker of the spec: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ky8cy8xVQKqyLAzeN03J?p=catalogue

Comment: 1) That's not a complete test. I can't guess what you're doing wrong. 2) The test doesn't even declare the middle component between the test component and the data table component. 3) Your using `@ViewChild('#myTable')`. You shouldn't use `#`. 4) I've tested it, and there is nothing wrong with the datatable. It's something wrong with your configuration. Other than that please post a _complete_ example if you need further help

Comment: Ok. I'll check the configurations. Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to get the configurations right. Here is a plunker of the more detailed code: https://plnkr.co/edit/QDKaMKZOKApRfuEkPuBx

Comment: Your example is still not complete so it's not something I can test. [Here is what I used to test](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/0bdbeb79bd08bac0e1b9e09e6e4d05a5), based on the code in your post

Comment: I'll look in to you example and update you about it.

Comment: I think the problem was I didn't put an  async in the it function. Thanks.