# Unable to test an input which is in ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jestjs, ng-template

As it says in the title, i'm trying to test an input which is in a ng-template. The problem is, that i can't access the input. If i take the input out from the ng-template, it works, but i need it inside the ng-template.

The code for the emp.html is from the primefaces documentation.
Link:https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table Filtering section

emp.html

```
<ng-template pTemplate="caption">         
 <div style="text-align: right">
  <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
   <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" 
   (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')"
   style="width:auto">
 </div>
</ng-template>
```

emp.component.spec.ts

```
describe('EmpComponent', () => {
let component: EmpComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<EmpComponent>;

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [SharedModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
    declarations: [ EmpComponent, TestTableComponent ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
      {provide: EmpService, useClass: MockEmpService},
    ]
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EmpComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeDefined();
});

it('check input', fakeAsync(() => {

  tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const inputElement = 
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;// Here it fails

  inputElement.value = 'some value';
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(inputElement.value).toEqual('some value');
  });  
}))
```

It gives the following error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

Comment: you want to test if `ng-template` has `pTemplate="caption"`?

Comment: No, i want to test the input which is in ng-template, basically, to give that input a value and then check if that value is in the input, the problem is that i can't access the input element if it is in ng-template

Answer (score 0):

You could write a TestComponent which mocks the table around your template (meaning it has the same selector) which just outputs the templates within.

In your test you could then test everything as you did before.

### Update 1

Just to make it a bit clearer what I meant earlier. Here is an example on how the TestTableComponent could look like. I haven't written this with an editor, so this is just an example and might not work out of the box, but just so you get an idea of what I meant:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'p-table',
 template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
class TestTableComponent {
  // I haven't worked with PrimeNG before, not sure whether this type gets exported
  @ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) templates: QueryList<PrimeTemplate>;
}
```

The `<ng-content></ng-content>` should display all content children which are of type PrimeTemplate. I haven't tried it, though. It might be necessary to get the templateRef from the PrimeTemplate elements as PrimeNG does it. If that's the case your TestTableComponent would look something like this:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'p-table',
 template: `<ng-container *ngFor="let template of templates"><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container></ng-container>`
})
class TestTableComponent implements NgAfterContentInit{
  // I haven't worked with PrimeNG before, not sure whether this type gets exported
  @ContentChildren(PrimeTemplate) primeTemplates: QueryList<PrimeTemplate>;

  templates: TemplateRef<any>[] = [];

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.templates.forEach((item) => {
      this.templates.push(item.template);
    });
}
```

Have a look [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/viewchildren-and-contentchildren/) for a bit more details about content projection
and it might help to have a look on how PrimeNG itself uses the content projection, to use the templates you provide to generate the tables [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts).

### Update 2

Here is a [stackblitz](https://content-projection-test.stackblitz.io) which demonstrates what I meant. I didn't want to add PrimeNG modules since I don't know which of them you are using and it isn't required to get the hang of what I've done. Therefore I copied PrimeNG's directive (PrimeTemplate) into the stackblitz. The directive is used to determine all content children. In your case all your ng-templates within the PrimeNG components have this directive.

The only remaining question is, whether PrimeTemplate can be imported from PrimeNG. You need to try that one out. If PimeNG doesn't export PrimeTemplate you might need to write your own directive and add it to all your templates you want to test. You can than use your own directive to collect the ng-templates. This wouldn't be as nice because you would add a directive only for testing purposes. So I hope PrimeNG exports this directive.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166854/angular-2-0-0-mocking-components

Comment: Yes. I would output the ViewChilds within the template of your TestComponent with <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet></ng-container>. So you can test your inputs and texts. I‘ll update my answer later on with an example TestComponent. I haven‘t got access to a computer atm and trying to write code on a mobile isn‘t much fun.

Comment: Ok, much appreciated.

Comment: So i've added the first part of your code, but the error still persists, do I have to change something in the test section? Also, in the second part of your code, the method add and .template are not recognized on type TemplateRef<any>

Comment: I made a stackblitz for you. I updated the answer with the link. Did you add your TestTableComponent to the declaration of your TestBed?

Comment: Yes, it's added in the declaration, but i don't see the link to the stackblitz

Comment: I was just updating the answer.  Now its there

Comment: The PrimeTemplate can be imported from PrimeNG. But i have a question, maybe this should have been the first question. Do i need to create another component, besides my main component? Because i already have a component which i'm testing, it's also added in the TestBed declarations. But, besides that, i have to create another component (TestTableComponent) with the code which you gave me and add it into the declarations? And afterwards, just run the tests on my main component exactly like before?

Comment: Yes in order to test your templates you need to mock the component which uses your templates. In your case you would need to mock the primefaces component (the table). The mock just outputs everything within the templates, so that you can access them in your test.

Comment: So basically your mock is using the templates just as the real table component does, but instead of putting one template content as caption and things like this, the mock just outputs the content of the templates, so that you can access that during you test.

Comment: I've updated my code in the emp.component.spec.ts(you can check it out), I added in the declarations the TestTableComponent but the error is still there but, do i have to change also which component i create?

Comment: you also need to add the directive (PrimeTemplate) in your decleration othewise its not possible to find the content children with that directive.

Comment: I've added PrimeTemplate into declarations, but it still gives the same error

Comment: Maybe you could create a stackblitz with what you did so far? It‘s a bit hard to try and find the error. Especially including your table test component and the tag around your templates.